# Which columns are being returned from an AJAX call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api

I know the names of some columns - `FirstName, LastName, JobTitle, SAMAccountName, Department` that an API serves out but I would like to know all the columns that are returned.

How do I find out the titles of all the columns?

The commented out line works.

```
$.ajax ({
//url: 'http://webservice/view/odata/PeopleDepartmentOData?$select=FirstName,LastName,JobTitle,SAMAccountName,Department',
url: 'http://webservice/view/odata/PeopleDepartmentOData',
dataType: 'json',
async: false,
headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
success: function(data) {
    var html = '';
    var count = 1;
var staffToShow = [];       

    for(var result in data.d.results) {

        
        console.log (data.d.results[result].FirstName + " - " + data.d.results[result].LastName);
        console.log (data.d.results[result].Department);
```

Comment: Are you trying to fetch the records from SharePoint list or user profiles or from somewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To know all the columns name, you can use below:

```
https://<TenantName>.sharepoint.com/sites/<SiteCollectionName>/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('<ListName>')/Fields?$filter=Hidden eq false and ReadOnlyField eq false&$select=Title,InternalName
```

Here,

`Title` = Display Name

`InternalName` = Internal Name of a column

Answer (score 0):

Examining the data returned from the web service call will get you the information you're looking for. There are a couple relatively easy ways to do this.

1. Use the web browser debugging tools. Put a debugger statement in the success method and examine the data object.

[image: Web browser debugging]

2. Use a tool like Fiddler (https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to capture the web traffic. Select the HTTP request in the left pane, select Inspectors in the right pane, and then select JSON in the Response pane.

[image: Fiddler]